# MySQL Table Indexes for 4-table Join

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have four tables:

```
activity (activity_id (PRIMARY), item_id, geolat, geolng, user_id, created_at)
users (user_id (PRIMARY), user_name, first_name, last_name, user_banned)
items (item_id (PRIMARY), item_name)
ratings (item_id (PRIMARY), avg_rating_score)
```

I'd like to run the following query:

```
SELECT item_name, count(distinct activity.user_id) as distinct_user_count, ratings.avg_rating_score
FROM activity
INNER JOIN users on activity.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN items on activity.item_id = items.item_id
INNER JOIN ratings on activity.item_id = ratings.item_id
WHERE activity.user_id != 1
AND (activity.geolat BETWEEN 'XXXXX' and 'XXXX' and activity.geolng BETWEEN 'XXXX' and 'XXXX') 
AND (users.user_banned = 0)
GROUP by activity.item_id
HAVING distinct_user_count >= 5
ORDER by avg_rating_score DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

I'm struggling with the right indexes for this join. Right now I have:

```
ALTER TABLE activity ADD INDEX (user_id)
ALTER TABLE activity ADD INDEX (item_id)
ALTER TABLE activity ADD INDEX (geolat)
ALTER TABLE activity ADD INDEX (geolng)
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX (user_banned)
```

The goal of the query is to obtain a list of items (within lat/lng radius) that at user 1 has never added, that have occurred at least 5 times in user 1's local area, ordered in descending order by the rating of that item, and finally not including any users that have been banned.

Is this the best approach? Is there a better way to tackle this query? It runs extremely slow with the index listed above.

Comment: you forget indexes for `ratings ( item_id)` (how many ratings do you have?) and consider to create both indexes for activity: `activity ( item_id, user_id, geolat, geolng  )` and `activity (  user_id, item_id, geolat, geolng  )`. What is more restritvite geolication or user_id and item_id ?

Comment: Ratings has around  70k rows. ITEM_ID is the primary key in that table. Does it make a different to do: activity ( item_id, user_id, geolat, geolng ) and activity ( user_id, item_id, geolat, geolng )? I updated my indexes as they are all single.

Comment: Remember that MySQL generate indexes for primary and foreign keys automatically. A composite index only has sense if optimizer look for all indexes fields (at least for the firsts fields).